# Pass Component Name from HTML to Component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

There is a scenario where in I want to make my Refactor my Angular Application.

I have a html where in on click of different button ,I want to open Dialog Box which are same in all respect except the component which opens on click of button.

`<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog('ComponentA')">Component A</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog('ComponentB')">Component B</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog('ComponentC')">Component C</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog('ComponentD')">Component D</button>`

On Click of button I call openDialog which in turn opens Dialog Box,whose structure depends on the Component Passed.

```
openDialog(component){
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
});
```

}

However, when I console component in openDialog,my component name appears as a simple string instead of complete component Structure.

I have already added my components in the entry component of my app.module.

Let me know,if the implementation I am trying is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as a string because 'ComponentA' refers to a string. You'll have import and pass the component constructor to your dialog box instead. Then in your dialog box component, inject the `ComponentFactoryResolver` service and `ViewContainerRef` to initialise the component:

**For Example**

`parent.component.ts`

```
import { ComponentA } from './component-a.component.ts';
import { ComponentB } from './component-b.component.ts';

class ParentComponent {
  public ComponentA = ComponentA;
  public ComponentB = ComponentB;

  @ViewChild('dialog') dialog;
}
```

`parent.component.html`

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="dialog.openDialog(ComponentA)">Component A</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="dialog.openDialog(ComponentB)">Component B</button>
```

`dialog-box.component.ts`

```
class DialogBoxComponent {
  constructor(private viewRef: ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  openDialog(componentConstructor) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentConstructor);
    const componentInstance = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    // add any initialisation you might need to do to componentInstance
  }

}
```

Note that components created in this manner won't have their `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators working. This is a limitation of the angular compiler which by design favours monomorphic components.

Therefore you'll have to manually set those properties of your child component that are reliant on `@Input()`. For `@Output()`, you'll have to manually subscribe to any event listeners on the component.